# not working form and form variable validation?

Tags: javascript, php, forms

***my form***

```
<div class="input-holder">
    <input type="text" class="search-input"  id="string"  placeholder="Искать" />
    <button class="search-icon" onclick="searchToggle(this, event);"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
</div>
```

***api.php***

```
case 'metafind': {
    $string = $_GET['string'];
    $list = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `sub_meta` WHERE `meta_key` = 'Название'&& `meta_value` ");
    while ($item = mysqli_fetch_assoc($list)) {
        if ($item['meta_value'] == $string) {
            $id = $item['post_id'];

            $arrr[] = array('post_id' => $item['post_id'], 'coords' => $find['meta_value']);
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($arrr);
} break;
```

when you click on the form gives an error in the console:

> (index):121 Uncaught ReferenceError: searchToggle is not defined
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):121)

it is necessary that when a word is entered into the form it was
searched for a name in the column meta_value by meta_key and then
displayed please help I'm new to php

Comment: Welcome. Do you have a Javascript function called `searchToggle()`? Doesn't seem so

Comment: this is javascript function "onclick"..

Comment: this function can be replaced with something ?

Comment: first you create function with the name of  `searchToggle()` in javascript and from js only you can call php file

Comment: Here you go. start with w3 school. https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_validation_js

Comment: "_this function can be replaced with something ?_" Depends on what `searchToggle()` is supposed to do, it's your code. Or did you copy that code from somewhere? Then I'd just remove the `onclick="searchToggle(this, event);"` part and see if your search does what it should and not bother

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like my below example :

1) I created textbox where i will write data then it will search in array and get the value from there where i have made array for example purpose and display the data in **#div1**

```
<div class="input-holder">
    <input type="text" class="search-input"  id="string"  placeholder="Искать" />
    <button class="search-icon"><i class="fas fa-search"></i>Go</button>
    <div id="div1"> </div>
</div>
```

2) When button click we have to do ajax call then we will get data from there and get that data in response and we will show that response where we want to display

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        var stringval = $("#string").val();

    $.ajax({data: {val : stringval} , url: "democode.php", type: 'post',  success:
         function(result){
            var data = JSON.parse(result);
             console.log(data);
     $("#div1").html(data);
    }});
  });
});
</script>
```

3) Ajax call on democode.php so in that file we will get data there(you can get data from database if you want) and we will  return the data

```
==democode.php==

    <?php

    $test['data'] = array("Aleaxa"=>"I'm Beutiful","john"=>"I'm Evil","mishel"=>"baby, I'm Bad Boy!","mohini"=>"I'm  MAstana");

    if (array_key_exists( $_POST['val'], $test['data'])) {
        $key = $_POST['val'];
         echo json_encode($test['data'][$key]);
    }

    ?>
```

So above example work like if i will search Aleaxa and click go button then it will give value of Aleaxa from array and output will be **I'm Beutiful**

**Please checked my demo you will get idea how to do the code with your requirements**